# PUT action type is incorrect in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, api, cakephp, httprequest, cakephp-3.0

I had problems with my PUT request in my CakePHP API, I couldn't change any attributes in my object, it only showed my object without modification. This problem conflicted with my authentication using the JWT-Auth plugin. I tried debugging and found in my AuthComponent that the action type of my put request is "view"

```
public function authCheck(Event $event)
{
    if ($this->_config['checkAuthIn'] !== $event->name()) {
            return null;
    }

    /* @var \Cake\Controller\Controller $controller */
    $controller = $event->subject();

    $action = strtolower($controller->request->params['action']);
    dd($action);
    if (!$controller->isAction($action)) {
         return null;
    }
[...]
```

This returns

```
<div class="cake-debug-output">
    <span>
        <strong>/src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php</strong> (line
        <strong>290</strong>)
    </span>
    <pre class="cake-debug">
&#039;view&#039;
</pre>
</div>
```

`dd($action);` returns my PUT request as 'view', here's my URL : PUT https://api.mysite.com/vehicules/1.json

What could be causing this problem?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Maybe your route isn't set up properly (check `bin/cake routes`), or your request cannot be identified as `PUT` (check `$controller->request->env('REQUEST_METHOD')` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`), or maybe you're actually not making a `PUT` request... pretty hard to tell from here, you gotta do some more debugging.

Comment: My route are correctly set, I can VIEW, INDEX, POST just fine. I'm using Postman for my request, I am sure that I am doing a put request. `$controller->request->env('REQUEST_METHOD')` returns action as view and method as GET with a PUT request.